# WordPress stripping some query vars from passed URL

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've got a plugin that passes values to other files using query vars. The var args are "state", "city", and "job". I'm facing an issue where WP is allowing the "state" var to pass correctly, but for "city" it is being blocked.

I checked their page regarding accepted query vars, and although none of the vars I mentioned above are listed, "state" is still working! To add to the frustration, I've had plugins with this exact functionality work in the past. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress strips query vars, you can use this function to add var names to a list to NOT strip out. Add it to your functions file:

```
function addnew_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] =  'city';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! For the add_filter function, what do the 10 and 1 mean?

Comment: Alas, it appears as though this code isn't working. The page was broken when implementing your code exactly, and wasn't working normally when I put the add_filter() part within the function. What do you think is happening, @David Nguyen?

Comment: @ZanderFields not sure what you mean

Comment: When I add the add_filter code, it breaks the site as if it were a php error. But there are definitely no syntax issues present when doing so.

Comment: @ZanderFields depends on the variable names, hard to tell without know your set up. if you are using a common name it may break something, anything in error logs?

Comment: None that I can see, unfortunately. I guess it'll have to remain a mystery for now, kinda unfortunate really. Thanks for following up I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out.
I had some troubles making it work, but looks like all fine after all.
Check here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars